# Blurred Plot after exporting to PDF

Tags: r, knitr

As the title suggests, I am struggling with a knitted plot.

In R, the appropriate plot will be displayed correctly, but in the pdf version, it is super blurred. I already tried to change the output with `fig.height` and so on, but no effects. (see links below)

Do you have an idea to solve this issue?

Exported PDF:
[image: exported in PDF]

In R:
[image: in R Studio]

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the code that you used to export to pdf.

Comment: Yeah, for sure, but is just this:

{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
vis_miss(df)

Comment: @JonasMorgner Please include other code too. Best would be if you would provide a reproducabe example. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for details.

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication, I am new in the programming scene here. Honestly, I don't know what I can provide you to solve the issue. With the plot, I just checked the percentage of my missing data in a specific data sample for each variable with vis_miss(dataframe)

So the plot is correct, but I am missing ways to make it smaller in PDF without distorting it

this is the settings for the knitting file

  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
  word_document: default
  html_document:
    df_print: paged

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue and eventually realised that my PDFs were not blurry at all and the issue was with the viewer (Edge, in my case). Zooming in on the plot revealed that the file was not truly blurry, and using a different viewer (e.g. Acrobat) showed a completely crisp plot.